# Permission error uploading user image via Django. The server is running as root, and the directory has 775 permissions

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-14.04

I am getting the following error when attempting to upload an image, when creating a new record in the admin interface.

`Permission denied: '/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test/static/uploaded_files/1407616465_2016587_61DjIaZQI8L.jpg'`

Relevant `settings.py` variables:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT=STATIC_ROOT
```

The output of

```
ls -l /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test/static/
```

is

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 jeffy jeffy 4096 Aug  9 16:32 uploaded_files
```

And the servers were started as user jeffy:

```
jeffy@originaldjangster:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo service nginx start
jeffy@originaldjangster:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/gunicorn_config.py django_test.wsgi
root
```

I placed this code at the end of `settings.py`

```
import getpass
print(getpass.getuser())
```

which is why "root" prints out after the gunicorn server is started.

---

Why can't this file be uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the original gunicorn_config.py file:

```
command = '/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test'
bind = '127.0.0.1:8001'
workers = 1
user = 'nobody'
```

Changing `nobody` to `jeffy` makes it work (although it balked at the static and media directories being equal...I made a `media` folder next to the `static` one).

This setup is only for me to show off my Django chops. If this were a production environment, I do get that running the server as root is a bad idea.

Not sure how "bad" this setup really is, but it's working at least so far...